predicting categorical result
im doing a clinical research for surgery. Main goal is to predict difficulty of operation with preoperatiive information. I found three variables as significant factor for difficulty of operation after linear logistic regression (both univariate and multivariate analysis).
Those 3 independent variables are continuous, categorical (binary) and categorical (binary). dependent variable is categorical (1,2 and 3 according to difficulty).
I want to then make some kind of scoring system to predict difficulty of operation. Is there any suggestion what model i can use?

If your dependent variable is categorical with 3 categories how did you perform logistic regression?

Have a look at multinomial regression - it's an extension of logistic regression when the dependent variable has more than two categories. You can then rank the difficulty based on the probability of each class
